# awk regular expression print every N occurence

Tags: regex, awk, pipe

I would like to understand awk a little better: I often search for regular expressions and many times I am interested only in the Nth occurrence. I always did this task using pipes say:

```
awk '/regex/' file | awk 'NR%N==0'
```

How can I do the same task with `awk` (or `perl`) **without piping**?

Are there some instances in which using pipes is the most computationally efficient solution?

Comment: you mean *every* Nth occurence, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every third:

```
awk '/line/ && !(++c%3)' infile
```

For example:

```
zsh-4.3.12[t]% cat infile
1line
2line
3line
4line
5line
6line
7line
8line
9line
10line
zsh-4.3.12[t]% awk '/line/ && !(++c%3)' infile
3line
6line
9line
zsh-4.3.12[t]% awk '/line/ && !(++c%2)' infile
2line
4line
6line
8line
10line
```

Comment: great! I can also specify if I want odd or even lines!   
awk '/regex/ && (++c%2==1)' file

Comment: Yes, or even: `awk '/regex/ && ++c % 2' file`

Answer (score 3):

Just count the occurences and print every other Nth:

```
BEGIN { n=0 }
/myregex/ { n++; if(n==3) { n=0; print } }
```

Comment: The BEGIN is optional here, n will default to 0.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber - You are right. My brain is damaged with so many years working on embedded systems, with mandatory variable initializations.

Comment: don't forget to accept this answer if you're satisfied with it!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
awk '/yourRegex/{i++} i==N{print; exit;}' yourFile
```

this will print only the Nth match

Oh, if you need **every Nth**

how about:

```
 awk '/yourRegex/{i++} (!(i%N) && i){print; i=0}' yourFile
```

Comment: Once `i==N`, this will print every line until the regular expression is seen again. Both forms have this problem.

Comment: your first solution prints also the lines following the Nth regex and the second one does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple conditions, e.g.:

```
awk -v N=10 '/regex/ { count++ } count == N { N=0; print $0 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/regex/ { c=(c+1)%N; if(c==0) print}' N=3
```

Comment: is this correct? if the first 100 lines don't match "regex", the will be all printed out? since c would be 0

Comment: @Kent: thx.. reverted it. originally it was ok, but then I thought I can simplify it and in the process I created a bug

Comment: thank You! Also I didn't know that possibility of writing N=3 thank you very much